# How Split a string a string in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have `${number}  123456789`

How to split this so that output is like following-

```
 *12345 6789*
```

Comment: Which programming language?

Answer (score 4):

**APPROACH#1** - Uses RF Built-in String and Collections to solve this problem

```
*** Settings ***
Library           String
Library     Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Case1
        @{characters} = Split String To Characters      123456789
        LOG TO CONSOLE  ${characters}
        ${x} =  Get Slice From List     ${characters}   0       5
        LOG TO CONSOLE  ${x}
        ${s1}=  Evaluate  "".join($x)
        LOG TO CONSOLE  ${s1}

       ${x2} =  Get Slice From List     ${characters}   5       10
        LOG TO CONSOLE  ${x2}
        ${s2}=  Evaluate  "".join($x2)
        LOG TO CONSOLE  ${s2}
```

**APPROACH#2** - Uses RF Built-in Evaluate to solve this problem

```
*** Settings ***
Library           String
Library     Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Case1
        LOG TO CONSOLE  USING ONLY MATHS
        ${result} =     Evaluate        123456789//10000
        LOG TO CONSOLE  ${result}

        ${result2} =     Evaluate        123456789%10000
        LOG TO CONSOLE  ${result2}
```

Comment: ${a} Get Substring ${number}  0 5
${b} Get Substring ${number} 5 9
${c}=    Set Variable   ${a} ${b}  This also is ok i think

Comment: Please accept the answer after it has worked for you.https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers